# Storing numbers that are odd and even

Tags: java, arrays

I am able to get the numbers from a `String` but it seems it only reads one digit of number example is if I input `Test24 XXX23`, it only reads `4` and `3` instead of `24` and `23`, also I need help in storing all numbers that are odd/even in an array and display them later like: Odd (3 5 7), Even(2 4 6)

```
public class acc2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter something with numbers:");
    String s = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");    
    String digits = s.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(digits);
    int len = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        i++;
        while (i < len && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
          System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
          if (s.charAt(i) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("is even");
          } else {
            System.out.println("is odd");
          }
          i++;
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
    }
    if (x <= 100) {
      if (x >= 50) {
        System.out.print(x + " passed");
      } else {
        System.out.print(x + " failed");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.print("Value is to high ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a bit all over the place here. Let's start with what this code does do and why it's not doing what you expect it to.  Specifically, why do you believe that this code is not producing the result you need it to?

Comment: i need help in storing the variables into an array which is checked in the while if stamement  and display them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the goal is, but I have a few suggestions. First, if you want to read 24 and 23 as two separate numbers instead of one (e.g., 2423 as done currently), then adjust `digits` to read `String[] digits = s.replaceAll("[^0-9.\\s+]", "").split("\\s+");` - this will create a string array of each number group defined as being separated by one or more spaces (i.e., 24 and 23 instead of 2423). Second, you can create two `Integer` lists, one for even and one for odd (for general consumption, it's impossible to know the length of each array (you could always use a huge number, but that's inefficient), which is why I suggest a list). You have the right idea in terms of a `%2` test for even/odd, just change the current iterators to iterate over each digit in each digit grouping:

```
for(int i=0; i<digits.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<digits[i].length(); j++){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String inp="Test24 XXX23";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");    
Matcher m=p.matcher(inp);
System.out.println(m.matches());
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
int[] even=new int[10];
int[] odd=new int[10];
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(inp.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    i=Integer.parseInt(inp.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    if(i%2==0){
        even[j]=i;j++;
    }

    else{
        odd[k]=i;k++;
    }


}
System.out.println(even[0]+" "+odd[0]);
>> Extend this program to print all odd and even numbers with for loop
```

Answer (score -1):

the following code extracts digits and also generate the array of odd and even numbers.This is what are you looking for.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class StackSolution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter something with numbers:");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        String digits = s.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
        int len = digits.length();
        Set<Integer>odd,even;
        odd=new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        even=new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                int no=Integer.parseInt(""+digits.charAt(i) );
                Integer dig=new Integer(no);
                if ( no%2==0) {
                    even.add(dig);
                } else {
                    odd.add(dig);
                }
        }
        int[] oddArray,evenArray;
        oddArray=new int[odd.size()];
        evenArray=new int[even.size()];
        oddArray=toIntArray(odd);
        evenArray=toIntArray(even);
        System.out.print("Odd: (");
        for(int no:oddArray){
            System.out.print(" "+no);
        }
        System.out.println(" )");
        System.out.print("Even: (");
        for(int no:evenArray){
            System.out.print(" "+no);
        }
        System.out.print(" )");
    }
    static int[] toIntArray(Set<Integer> list){
          int[] ret = new int[list.size()];
              Iterator<Integer> itr=list.iterator();
              int i=0;
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Integer integer = (Integer) itr.next();
                ret[i]=integer.intValue();
                i++;
            }
          return ret;
        }
}
```